# Hide div with the trigger of the function inside the div

Tags: javascript, html

Maybe is not easy to understand from the title but im trying to make a login/register form with only javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="prueba.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Div1">
        <form class="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
            <button>login</button>
            <p class="message">Not registered?
                <button onclick="switchVisible()">Register</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="Div2">
        <form class="register-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="email address" />
            <button>create</button>
            <p class="message">Already registered?
                <button onclick="switchVisible()">Login</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <button onclick="switchVisible()">Swap</button>

    <script src="prueba.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Swap button works fine but the ones inside form dont. I want to leave just the ones inside the form.

Edit: prueba.js

```
function switchVisible() {
            if (document.getElementById('Div1')) {

                if (document.getElementById('Div1').style.display == 'none') {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'none';
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('Div1').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('Div2').style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
}
```

Basically, what i want to show is only one form, if you are on the login form, you can press the "Register" from "Not registered yet?" and it will show the register form, and viceversa.

If you check https://www.instagram.com/ login page you will get it. The thing is i want the swap button to be personalized, but the button only works if its outside the div i want to hide/show.

Comment: Could you include some of the javacript for switchVisible() or include a link to prueba.js I can't seem to find much on it. Or better phrase what you want the 'swap' button to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041874/how-to-select-a-button-inside-a-form-tag-with-javascript

Comment: i added the javascript code, and gowtham, i think that question is about jquery.

Comment: just created a basic version of this: https://jsfiddle.net/bv5m42od/ . Unless there's more going on in prueba.js that we can't see, then the issue could be that the buttons inside the divs are submitting the form. Adding the attribute ` type="button"` to the `<button>` tags would prevent this, and allow the Javascript to execute before the page is posted back (see this version: https://jsfiddle.net/bv5m42od/1/). Is that what's happening to you? You said "Not working" but gave no further details.

Comment: @ADyson you are right, the problem was that the button submited the form so the page was refreshing after calling the function. I relocate the button inside the div tag, but ouside the form tag, and now it works fine. I can upvote you if you write an answer.

Comment: @Mr.X I just did so, thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a basic demo of this issue: https://jsfiddle.net/bv5m42od .

It appears that the issue is that the buttons inside the divs are submitting the form before the JavaScript can be executed.

Adding the attribute `type="button"` to the `<button>` tags will prevent this, and allow the Javascript to execute before the page is posted back, e.g:

```
<button type="button" onclick="switchVisible()">Register</button>
```

See working example:  https://jsfiddle.net/bv5m42od/1

As another alternative, you could simply place these buttons outside the `<form>` tags, without needing to add the attribute.